# Pandas: how to subtract the mean column of a sparse dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix

In pandas 0.25.3, I can't subtract the mean column of a sparse dataframe. I tried:

`df_norm= df.sub(df.mean(axis=1), axis=0)`

but I get:

`AttributeError: module 'pandas._libs.sparse' has no attribute 'sparse_sub_float32'`

Comment: no, because you subtract the mean row, and I want the mean column

Comment: mmm, your code works for me, try restart the kernel

Comment: I already restarted the kernel many times, it's a large SPARSE dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have this error if you use older Pandas `SparseDataFrame` structure. However in latest Pandas (I use 0.25.3) there is a different way to deal with sparse and your code works fine. Consider converting your dataframe into the modern sparse type. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#sparse-migration.
Below is a working example

```
df = pd.DataFrame (np.random.randint(0,100,(5,5)))
dtype = pd.SparseDtype(int, fill_value=0)   # define sparse type
df = df.astype(dtype)  # to new sparse type
print(df.sub(df.mean(axis=1), axis=0))

      0     1     2     3     4
0 -28.6  43.4 -42.6 -14.6  42.4
1  29.4  25.4 -48.6  -4.6  -1.6
2 -12.4  52.6 -15.4 -17.4  -7.4
3 -20.8  -2.8  10.2  -6.8  20.2
4  35.8  -4.2  19.8 -16.2 -35.2
```

Comment: I have version 0.25.3

Comment: then try converting your data into this newer sparse structure, and see if this works. 
I mean if SparseDataFrame is deprecated and modern SparseDtype solvesyour issue, why not upgrading the data? I assume that the link to Pandas docs which I provided shows clear way to convert the data.